# Showing that a set of functions is dense in $L^{p}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

> Let $f \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$, for $h>0$ define:
>
> $f_{h}(x)=\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt$
>
> Show that $f_{h}$ is continuous and that continuous functions are dense in $L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$, by showing $||f_{h}-f||_{p} \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

I know this seems like a really easy question, but I don't know where to start. What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

By the integral form of Minkowski's inequality $\|f_h-g_h||_p <\epsilon$ if $\|f-g\|_p <\epsilon$. Any $f$ in $L^{p}$ can be approximated in the $L^{p}$ norm by a  bounded measurable function with compact support. [Just look at $fI_A$ where $A=\{x:|f(x)| \leq N,|x|\leq N\}$ with $N$ large enough]. Hence it suffices to prove the result when $f$  is a  bounded measurable function with compact support.  In that case we can use Lebesgue's Theorem (which tells you that $f_h \to f$ almost everywhere ) along with DCT to prove that $\|f_h-f||_p  \to 0$ as $h \to 0$. Let me know if a more detailed answer is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I get it. For the first equation, wouldn't it be $||f_{h}-g_{h}||_{p} < \epsilon$ if $||f-g||_{p} < \epsilon$? Also, why would $f_{h}$ be continuous? I still can't see that....

Comment: @fenetre Yes, there was a typo. $\int_x^{x+h} f(t)\, dt=\int_0^{x+h} f(t)\, dt-\int_0^{x} f(t)\, dt$ and indefinite integrals of integrable functions are continuous. Hence $f_h$ is continuous.