# How to show that $C[0,1]$ is dense in $L_1[0,1]$, using the "absolute continuity of integral"?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Here $C[0,1]$ means the family of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $L_1[0,1]$ means the Lebesgue integrable funstions on $[0,1]$. Professor said that the key point is the "absolute continuity of integral".

I know the proof by decomposing $f=f^+-f^-$ and use the definition of integral to know the density of simple functions. And then use step functions to approach simple functions. Then it is easy to approach step function by continuous function.

But I'm confused with the usage of "absolute continuity of integral". I tried to use the absolute continuity of integral with Lusin's Theorem, but I got no way to expand the continuous functon $\left. f\right|_E$ to a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Hint: Can you prove it for functions in $L^{\infty}[0,1]?$

Comment: See this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3077872/showing-that-a-set-of-functions-is-dense-in-lp), this should anwser your question.

Comment: its very strange the question indeed. From a point of view of functional analysis we can define a linear functional $I:C[0,1]\to \mathbb{R},\, f\mapsto \int_{0}^1 f(x)\,d x$ where the integral is the integral of Riemann. Then the completion of the space $C[0,1]$ is $L_1[0,1]$

Comment: Thanks for comments! I think @ムータンーオ 's link works.

Comment: And, I think @zhw. 's hint means $C[0,1]\subset L_\infty[0,1]$ and it suffices to show $L_\infty[0,1]$ is dense in $L_1[0,1]$. However, I can't find where the "absolute continuity of integral" is used.

Comment: @Masacroso : Professor said that $(C[0,1],\| \ \|_{L_1})$ 's completion is $L_1[0,1]$ but this was proved in the next lecture, by the theorem of completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{C}$ denote the closure of $C[0,1]$ in $L^1[0,1]$.

If $\mathscr{C}\ne L^1[0,1]$, then there is a $\phi\in L^1[0,1]^*$ such that $\phi\ne 0$, and such that $\phi$ vanishes on $\mathscr{C}$. Because $L^1[0,1]^*=L^\infty[0,1]$, then that would give the existence of $0\ne f\in L^\infty[0,1]$ such that $\int_0^1 g(t)f(t)dt=0$ for all $g\in C[0,1]$. By a simple limiting argument involving $g$, you can conclude that $\int_0^x f(t)dt=0$ for all $x$. By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, it follows that $f=0$ a.e., which is the contradiction that proves $\mathscr{C}=L^1[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Confusion : If you want to accept my answer, you can select the checkmark beside your question.